# I cant see logs on terminal when I launch my ionic app on my phone

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

Im building an app on ionic, my problem is that I want to see the console logs in real time when I launch the app on my android phone.

I used this command:

```
sudo ionic cordova run android
```

It launchs the app without problem. But looking on internet I saw that if I add `-l`I can see the logs while the app is running on my phone. The problem is that when I execute:

```
sudo ionic cordova run android -l
```

It shows this error:

```
> cordova build android --device
[INFO] ... and 77 additional chunks
[ng] ℹ ｢wdm｣: Compiled successfully.
> native-run android --app platforms/android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk --device --forward 8100:8100
[native-run] Selected hardware device 1c675858050c
[native-run] Error: Command failed: /root/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb -s 1c675858050c reverse tcp:8100 tcp:8100
[native-run] adb: error: closed
[native-run] 
[native-run]     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:303:12)
[native-run]     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:321:20)
[native-run]     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1026:16)
[native-run]     at Socket.<anonymous> (internal/child_process.js:441:11)
[native-run]     at Socket.emit (events.js:321:20)
[native-run]     at Pipe.<anonymous> (net.js:668:12)
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess native-run.

        native-run android --app platforms/android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug... exited with exit code
        1.

        Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
```

How can I solve it? Or am I doing something wrong to see the logs in console while I use the ap on my phone?

Thanks!

Comment: you can debug and see consoles in google chrome. Type `chrome://inspect/` in your chrome and select your connected devices and you can see logs and other stuff.

Comment: Thanks for ur answer! But in my pc or using chrome in my phone? And the command is with or without "-l"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connect Your Device via Cable or `adb` to run your application build.

After installation:

1) Open Chrome in your PC and type `chrome://inspect/` you will a list you connected devices.
[image]

2) click on `inspect` a New chrome Windows will open with your application running in it.

Comment: Im using ubuntu, Will work with chromium? and the command to run my app is this "sudo ionic cordova run android" ,no?